# Are there any http clients for nodesj that respect the http/1.1 max-age cache-control header?

Tags: node.js, cache-control

I've seen a few http client and proxy implementations for nodejs but none respect http/1.1 caching headers.
My nodejs apps is a client of an http service that provides a max-age on the cache-control header in the response. The value varies across requests. I'd lie to cache the response as a browser would do i.e. respecting the cache-control header.

Comment: If you're still interested in such modules, the [`requestify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/requestify) module might work for your needs.